# How to set cache-control to max-age=0 with github s3 sync action

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, continuous-deployment, cache-control, github-actions

I am uploading a vue app to my s3 bucket on every merge to master. My problem is that the invalidation of the cache does not fully work. My next step is adding a metadata to the object `index.html` on every push. For that I wanted to ask how to add it in the github action `jakejarvis/s3-sync-action` (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/s3-sync)?

Or do I have to use another github action to accomplish that?

My workflow looks  like that at the moment:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js 12.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'

      - name: npm install
        run: |
          npm ci
      - name: build
        run: |
          npm run build

      - name: Deploy to S3
        uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
          args: --acl public-read --delete
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_STAGING_BUCKET_NAME }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          SOURCE_DIR: 'dist'

      - name: Invalidate cloudfront
        uses: muratiger/invalidate-cloudfront-and-wait-for-completion-action@master
        env:
          DISTRIBUTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_STAGING_DISTRIBUTION_ID }}
          PATHS: '/*'
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

The result I am looking for is that the `index.html` has another metadata `Cache-Control: max-age=0` after every deployment. At the moment I am adding it by hand in the s3 management console which is not a good solution for me. Because the metadata is gone after every deployment.

I found answers on how to do it with the aws-cli but I don't know it it is possible to add that in my action.

```
aws s3 cp s3://[mybucket]/index.html s3://[mybucket]/index.html --metadata-directive REPLACE \
--expires 2034-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=0,public
```

PS: I know I need to write tests

Answer (score 2):

In your example:

```
    with:
      args: --acl public-read --delete
```

`args` takes effect because it's passed through as-is to the [`aws s3` invocation](https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action/blob/0facb2201e4ea106a491c765ff0141dee4f9660b/entrypoint.sh#L42), which has `$*` at the end:

```
sh -c "aws s3 sync ${SOURCE_DIR:-.} s3://${AWS_S3_BUCKET}/${DEST_DIR} \
              --profile s3-sync-action \
              --no-progress \
              ${ENDPOINT_APPEND} $*"
```

If you'd also like to set `--cache-control max-age=0,public` then add it to the `args`:

```
    with:
      args: --acl public-read --delete --cache-control max-age=0,public
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If understand it correct in this case all the files would get a `cache-control max-age=0` or? The thing is that I just want to have the `index.html` to have those meta-tag.

Comment: Yes, this would set it for all files. I think you would need a second invocation to have separate `--cache-control` for different files.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So do you mean I would need to fork the action and add another script?